# Toggle-only sidenav with Angular-Material?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want a side menu that is closed by default on any screen size, and will always open on top of other content. No matter what I try though, it always switches at widths over 960px.

This is what my menu looks like now:

```
<md-sidenav is-locked-open="false" class="md-sidenav-right md-whiteframe-z2" component-id="right">
    <md-toolbar class="md-theme-dark">
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <md-button ng-click="toggleMenu()" class="md-button-colored"><core-icon icon="polymer"></core-icon></md-button>
            <span flex></span>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content class="md-content-padding">
        <md-button ng-click="toggleMenu()" class="md-button-colored">Stuff</md-button>
    </md-content>
</md-sidenav>
```

And my controller:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $mdSidenav) {
    $scope.toggleMenu = function() { $mdSidenav('right').toggle(); };
})
```

I got is-locked-open from the [website](https://material.angularjs.org/#/api/material.components.sidenav/directive/mdSidenav) but I can't find that anywhere in their javascript.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [is-locked-open](https://material.angularjs.org/#/api/material.components.sidenav/directive/mdSidenav) attribute in md-sidenav to control the locking open of the sidenav. This will lock the sidenav when browser width is 1000px.

```
<md-sidenav is-locked-open="$media('min-width: 1000px')"></md-sidenav>
```

To have is forever unlocked, this worked for me:

```
<md-sidenav is-locked-open="$media('')"></md-sidenav>
```

Comment: Actually, since I posted this question there has been an update. Now you can just use the class "md-closed" on md-sidenav.

Comment: Awesome, that's definitely useful and cleaner. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

sidenav to be hidden all time by commenting out following style in angular-material.css

`@media (min-width: 960px) {
     md-sidenav {
      /* position: static;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important; }
  .md-sidenav-backdrop {
    display: none !important;*/ } }`